# how do i solve this Error 'tuple' object is not an iterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, keras-layer

I am a beginner in AI need some help in the following code.

```
valcall = val_images,Yval_images
traincall = train_images,Ytrain_images

callbacks = [
     EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15, verbose=1, min_delta=1e-5),
     ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, cooldown=0, verbose=1, min_lr=1e-8),
     ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_loss', filepath='/content/drive/My Drive/TPU/testchange.hdf5', verbose=1,save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto')

    ]

    model.fit_generator( traincall, epochs=epochs,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=valcall)
```

I am getting this error on training the model i am confused what **tuple** do i need to change in object ? please help me out thanks.

I am getting this error : [image]

Comment: convert it to list?

Comment: The error message shown doesn't relate to the code shown. Also, please don't post screenshots of text - copy and paste the text, and use the formatting tools.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you for pointing that out. 

I should clear myself error was on this line as show above 

`model.fit_generator( traincall, epochs=epochs,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=valcall) `


and this line is present in the **train_model** function on which the error occur as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a distinction between an iterable value and an iterator in Python. An iterable value (like a `tuple`) is one that you can pass to `iter` and get an iterator for it.

```
>>> t = (1, 2)
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(iter(t))
<class 'tuple_iterator'>
```

An iterator is something you can pass to `next` and get back the next value, as determined by the iterator's internal state.

```
>>> itr = iter(t)
>>> next(itr)
1
>>> next(itr)
2
```

As you can see, a tuple is iterable, but not an iterator.

---

There are two reasons, IMO, why this distinction is often overlooked.

1. Most uses of iterators are by functions and constructs that request an iterator from an iterable, meaning you rarely need to work with iterators directly. For example, you may write `for i in some_list: ...`, but the `for` loop gets the list iterator `iter(some_list)` for you.
2. Some iterable objects, like file-like objects, act as their own iterators.

   ```
   >>> f = open(".zshrc")
   >>> f is iter(f)
   True
   ```

Comment: Your explanation was helpful Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in Fit_generator's 1st argument **' traincall '**, I was passing two variables containing multiple images Like this.

`traincall = train_images,Ytrain_images`

but i guess Fit_generator cannnot take multiple variables containing images this was so i had to make a separate function that could yield images one by one in batches like this:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, rotation_range=20, horizontal_flip=True)
def image_a_b_gen(images, batch_size):
    while True:
        for batch in datagen.flow(images, batch_size=batch_size):
            yield getImages(batch)
```